# Google Apps Script issue in copying sheet: "Service Spreadsheets Failed While Accessing Document with ID"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

First time in Stack Overflow. My English is also not that good. Apologize.

I have a Google Apps Script which copies some sheets to another spreadsheet. The sheets have around 30 columns and 55 rows, and they might contain 1 or 2 images, some formatting, and conditional formatting. The app suddenly stopped working, after some weeks of occasional error.

Here is an example of the spreadsheet with the sheets I need to copy: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WgT5fLjNseSZcXWyuzYcz3d3JLlOW5EmUNH60jjkShk/edit#gid=416376495

The original code goes like this, which returns an error "service spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id" in the "copyTo" line.

```
let ss_editora = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id_ss_editora);
let ss_ficha = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id_ss_ficha);
let ss_editora_sheets = ss_editora.getSheets();
let ss_ficha_sheets = ss_ficha.getSheets();

let ren_ficha = ss_editora.insertSheet();
for (let i = 0; i < ss_editora_sheets.length; i++) { ss_editora.deleteSheet(ss_editora_sheets[i]) }

for (let i = 0; i < ss_ficha_sheets.length; i++) {
  let ss_ficha_sheet = ss_ficha_sheets[i];
  let nova_sheet = ss_ficha_sheet.copyTo(ss_editora); // Error
  nova_sheet.setName(ss_ficha_sheet.getName());
}
ss_editora.deleteSheet(ren_ficha);
```

I've tried to simply remove images, this seems to work, but I do need the images.

Also, I've tried to rewrite the code without copyTo, by using Bing AI. But it returns an error "service spreadsheets timed out while accessing document with id" in the "setValues" line, even if I remove the images.

```
function copySheets(id_ss_ficha, id_ss_editora) {
  const ss_ficha = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id_ss_ficha);
  const ss_editora = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id_ss_editora);

  let ss_editora_sheets = ss_editora.getSheets();
  let ren_ficha = ss_editora.insertSheet();
  for (let i = 0; i < ss_editora_sheets.length; i++) { ss_editora.deleteSheet(ss_editora_sheets[i]) };

  const ss_ficha_sheets = ss_ficha.getSheets();
  ss_ficha_sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    const nova_sheet = ss_editora.insertSheet();
    const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    nova_sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data); // Error
    const images = sheet.getImages();
    sheet.copyTo()
    images.forEach(image => {
      const blob = image.getBlob();
      const imageFile = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
      const imageBlob = imageFile.getBlob();
      const imagePosition = image.getAnchorCell().getA1Notation();
      nova_sheet.insertImage(imageBlob, imagePosition);
    });
    const conditionalFormats = sheet.getConditionalFormats();
    const ranges = conditionalFormats.getRangeList();
    const rules = conditionalFormats.getRules();
    ranges.forEach(range => {
      range.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
    });
    nova_sheet.setName(sheet.getName());
  });

  ss_editora.deleteSheet(ren_ficha);
}
```

How do I fix this? It seems like an issue (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156530211, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/317861129), but I do need a workaround.

Comment: Please post everything needed to answer the question in the question.  Personally, I do not follow links to offsite resources

Comment: Which document did the failure occur on and what line in your code did it happen?

Comment: Hi @Cooper , thanks for the availability! The document is another spreadsheet containing the script that copies the sheets (as the ones described). 

The failure line is: `let nova_sheet = ss_ficha_sheet.copyTo(ss_editora);`

After trying to rewrite the code without copyTo, the failure line became:  `nova_sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data)`

Comment: What is the exact error now?

Comment: @ArthurPaiva, for what it's worth, I tried your original script (the one with copyTo) and did not encounter any errors copying sheets from one spreadsheet to another. I only encountered the error you mentioned when attempting to copy sheets **to or from** an Excel file in Google Drive. Can you confirm that both the source sheet and the destination sheet are Google Sheets files?